# WASI interface in wasmtime-dotnet print to stdout

Tags: .net, webassembly, wasi, wasmtime

I'm trying to use the WASI interface in *wasmtime-dotnet*
. I am trying to print to *stdout*. - I  also want to read input and so on. Here's the WebAssembly Text (wat) code that I'm using for testing:

```
(module
  (type $write_type (func (param i32 i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_write" (func $fd_write (type $write_type)))
  (memory (export "memory") 1)
  (data (i32.const 8) "Hello, WASI!\n")

  (func $main (result i32)
    ;; Prepare parameters for fd_write
    i32.const 1         ;; File descriptor (1 represents stdout)
    i32.const 8         ;; Pointer to the data to be written
    i32.const 13        ;; Length of the data
    i32.const 0         ;; Pointer to store the number of bytes written (not used in this example)

    ;; Call fd_write
    call $fd_write
  )

  (export "main" (func $main))
)
```

Wasmtime Version=9.0.2

I have set up wasmtime-dotnet like so:

```cs
            var config = new Config()
                .WithDebugInfo(true)
                .WithCraneliftDebugVerifier(true)
                .WithOptimizationLevel(0);

            _engine = new Engine(config);
            _linker = new Linker(_engine);
            _store = new Store(_engine);

            var config = new WasiConfiguration().WithInheritedStandardOutput()
                .WithInheritedStandardInput()
                .WithInheritedArgs()
                .WithInheritedStandardError()
                .WithInheritedEnvironment();

            _store.SetWasiConfiguration(config);
            _linker.DefineWasi();
```

The code is running without any errors, and the main function returns 21.